# Can we remove the Watermark that is slightly lighter than the greyscale image using photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Grey scale image with watermark]

Need to remove the background word "confidential" from all the locations for QC purposes

Can this be achieved in photoshop or any other software.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's okay to post this image?

Comment: I think this might be confidential

Comment: Yes this can be done pretty easily in fact. But i wont tell how to do this because its a bit unethical to say the least..

Answer (score 3):

I only see two options here:

1. Go in and manually erase each bit of the watermark by hand around
   the letters (extremely time consuming).
2. Find out what font that is (or find a similar one) and retype it
   word for word.

Actually, there are three options.

The last one (bear with me, I know this may sound crazy) you could ask the source that you got this from for permission to use it and for an unwatermarked image ;)